# How to pass environment variable to C++ program in Unix

Tags: c++, linux, unix, environment-variables

I recently wrote a C++ program that opens a file and reads it. If I want to run the program in Unix/Linux and the file name and path will be a environment variable. How can I achieve it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `getenv(char const *name)` of the `stdlib.h`. Note, however, that environment variables are a quite unclean way to pass parameters.

Comment: Hi，I just wrote        ` char* var;`
        `var = getenv("CDDB");`
        `ifstream input;`
        `input.open(var);`
But the file stored in `$CDDB` cannot be read.

Comment: @RunningPig If you have another question, just post another question as a question, not as a comment. If it is a debugging question, make sure to include a [mcve].